# Play evolution not applied in custom Slick environment configuration

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, playframework-evolutions

## DESCRIPTION:

Hi. I am using `Play framework` and `Slick` and `PostgreSQL` for my application. So I design [CI_Pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) and configure them in my `application.conf`.When we set slick configuration like this:

```
play.evolutions.db.default {
  enabled = true
  autoApply=true
} 
slick.dbs.default {
driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
db {
    driver=org.postgresql.Driver
    dbName=dbName
    url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/dbName"
    user=***
    password=***
   }
}
```

and in codes (dao files):

```
@Singleton
class UserDao @Inject()(
                       protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider
                       )(implicit val ex: ExecutionContext) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import driver.api._
  val userTableQuery = TableQuery[UserTable]
```

everything works all write such as `EVOLUTION` that `play` provided for us.
But if you want to setup other environments such as `staging` or `production` you will fail :D.
 I read this documentation of `Slick` you can read it from [here](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.0-M2/database.html) that is perfect for writing a successful config file. so I write it like this:

```
com.my.org {
env = "development"
env = ${?MY_ENV}
development {
  db {
    dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
    properties = {
      driver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
      user = "myuser"
      password = "*****"
      url = "jdbc:postgresql://myIP/dbName"
    }
    numThreads = 10
  }
}
staging {
db {
    ip=186.14.*.*
    ...
   }
}
production {
db {
    ip=196.82.*.*
    ...
   }
}
}
```

** The important thing that you must attention to it, is my `PostgreSQL` is outside of my (docker container) so I must connect to it remotely.

and in code we have :

```
    class UserDao @Inject()(
                       )(implicit val ex: ExecutionContext) {

  import driver.api._
  val db = Database.forConfig(s"$prefix.db")
  val userTableQuery = TableQuery[UserTable]
```

## PROBLEM:

Problem is now play evolution does not applied.

## QUESTION:

I need to know how to implement one of this (to solve my problems):

1. how to apply play evolution in this way described before (in problem part) ?
2. how to setup my environments in better way ?

Comment: How do you read your application.conf in your code?

Comment: Good comment .Tnx. I add it to question body

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine consulted me about the problem [over the phone] and here is the solution we came up with:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db {
  driver = org.postgresql.Driver
  ip = localhost
  dbName = ***
  user = ***
  password = "***"
  url="jdbc:postgresql://postgresql/"${slick.dbs.default.db.dbName}
}
```

You can also use Docker to create a docker network and set your `PostgreSQL` container name instead of your IP address.

Also, if you want to be be able to configure the `IP` address, say from [jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) or [Play_Runtime_Guice](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaDependencyInjection), you can use this:

```
url="jdbc:postgresql://"${?POSTGRESQL_IP}"/dbName"
```